# Windows Batch script to download N latest files from FTP and feed them to an EXE file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I am more familiar with Bash and in Bash what I am doing here would be easy.

I would like to create a Windows batch script to download the N latest files from an FTP server and then feed the filenames to an EXE as command line parameters.

The code would be doing the following:

```
open ftp test.com
username
password
"get/download N latest files from the ftp folder" 
"list N latest files just downloaded"
"for each filename execute 'mytest.exe filename' as a background job (in Bash: &)"
```

I think that to run a process asynchronously, I can use the START command.

How can this be achieved using a Batch script or the command line?

Comment: Where's the part of the script where you actually download the files? I don't see a `get` or an `mget`.

Comment: MS-DOS doesn't support background jobs so what you're asking is impossible. If you really mean from the Windows command prompt then you should edit your answer to ask how to do this under Windows and not  under a long obsolete 16-bit operating system.

Comment: You might consider using Cygwin which would allow to you use bash on Windows.

Comment: i think he don't know how to do it with cmd but know to do with bash.. @SomethingDark

Answer (score 1):

You can use following PowerShell script using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library):

```powershell
param (
    $sessionUrl = "ftp://user:mypassword@example.com/",
    $localPath = "c:\\downloaded\\",
    $remotePath = "/home/user/",
    $count = 10
)

# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl);

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

# Get list of files in the directory
$directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

# Select the most recent file
$latestFiles =
    $directoryInfo.Files |
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -First $count

# Download the latest files
foreach ($latestFile in $latestFiles)
{
    Write-Host "Downloading $latestFile..."

    $sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $latestFile.Name)
    $session.GetFiles($sourcePath, $localPath).Check()
}

# Disconnect, clean up
$session.Dispose()
```

This is based on an official example [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating an FTP script in a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo YOURUSERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo YOURPASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat

:: DO WHATEVER YOU NEED HERE
  echo quote SYST>> ftpcmd.dat
  echo quote FEAT>> ftpcmd.dat
  echo PWD>> ftpcmd.dat
  echo quote PASV>> ftpcmd.dat
  echo ASCII>> ftpcmd.dat
  echo LIST>> ftpcmd.dat
:: END

echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.YOURSERVER.com > ftp.log
del ftpcmd.dat
```

By now, you have an ftp.log with the file list.
Now, you can do the rest with batch file, but it would be MUCH easier if you uses a real programming language.

Back to the batch file...

- To interpret ftp.log and list the latest 10 files you can use FOR command.
- To download the 10 files you can create another FTP script with GET command
- To start a process in the background you can use START